# How to do data serialization in C#?

Tags: c#, serialization, console-application

Working on my project. I have to do data serialization.

I have a code but I don't know how to apply serialization on it.

```
public class allmethods
{
    private static string Name;
    private static int ID;
    private static int Age;
    private static string Email;
    private static string output;

                public static void WritingMethod()  
          {
                int count = 0;
                while (count < 10)
             {
                    Console.Write(" Enter your Name: ");
                    Name = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.Write(" Enter your ID: ");
                    ID = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.Write(" Enter your Age: ");
                    Age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.Write(" Enter your E-mail: ");
                    Email = Console.ReadLine();



                    StreamWriter Sw = new StreamWriter("fileone.txt", true);
                    string output = string.Format("Thank you for registration! Your Submitted information are:" + Environment.NewLine + "Name: {0}"
                    + Environment.NewLine + "ID: {1}" + Environment.NewLine + "Age: {2}" + Environment.NewLine + "E-mail: {3}", Name, ID, Age, Email);
                    Console.WriteLine(output);      
                    Sw.WriteLine(output + Environment.NewLine);
                    Console.ReadLine();

                    Sw.Close();
                    count++;
             }
         }
     }
```

I'd be glad if anyone helped me with this. Thank you.

Comment: What would you like to serialise this as

Comment: one easy and low hanging fruit to start with: C# and DOM ( XML serializer )
: http://www.mastercsharp.com/Article/69/working-with-xml-dom

Answer (score 1):

Serialization and deserialization is a very large topic and won't fit a single question.

However, since you're asking where to start, I would suggest you research the `ISerializable` interface.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx

Good luck.

Comment: +1 for ISerializable pointer. But I felt a great disturbance in the force when you wished him "Good luck" - programming should not depend on luck ( mostly )

Comment: Futher info: [`DataContracts`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx) are probably the best thing to start with when implementing `ISerializable`.

Comment: @Najzero It's an expression. I don't think I ever heard someone say "Work well." or "Your efforts shall be rewarded." when talking about work.

Comment: @MarcGravell Really? I never needed more than that.

Comment: @LightStriker that API suggests BinaryFormatter is in use, which has more subtle quirks than a subtle quirky thing on a subtle quirky weekend break.

Comment: @MarcGravell You're aware that sentence doesn't make much sense. Why would implementing `ISerializable` only limit you to using a single serializer? The only method it asks to implement is `GetObjectData` which I think all serializer can uses... Unless you implement them "manually", which I never understood why people would do that.

Comment: @LightStriker it is the serializer most commonly associated with that interface. Most serializers don't even consider it.

Comment: @MarcGravell Seriously, I never understood why people make it harder than it is. I never cared what serializer is used because they all do the same thing. I made myself a base class from which every other derived and it handles all the serialization, and I can plug in whatever serializer I want. The only problem I had to research was recursive references in XML file and even that is quite easy to solve.

Comment: @LightStriker seeing as XmlSerializer doesn't use that interface AFAIK, that sounds unlikely

Comment: @MarcGravell When did I ever say that it does? I only said I made a base class that handle serialization, no matter the formatter used.

Comment: @Light ah. Earlier you were talking about ISerializable.  Inheritance then raises a whole new set of complexities - and forcing all your DTOs down a particular base model has a lot of code-stink about it

Comment: @MarcGravell My guess is at that point, it's a matter of philosophy. Most video game engines follow that pattern by having a single base class that handle the serialization and it makes life a lot easier, by having a few specific attributes that can modify the serialization behavior directly on the fields or the properties. Once you got that in place, you never touch it ever again. It even allows you to do deep duplication of object with a few lines of code! Why people feels the need to rewrite a serialization handler all the time is simply beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at these [examples](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/cs4ch16.aspx) from a book C# in a Nutshell. Reading the chapter on serialization would also help.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is get rid of those static fields; most serializers work on objects... so let's create a `class`:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

so our main logic becomes:

```
var person = new Person();
Console.Write(" Enter your Name: ");
person.Name = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write(" Enter your ID: ");
person.ID = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write(" Enter your Age: ");
person.Age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write(" Enter your E-mail: ");
person.Email = Console.ReadLine();
```

Next we need to ask - "what serialization format do we want?". It looks like you are appending. Normally I'd say "start with something simple like `XmlSerializer` or JSON", but neither of those is appendable. `BinaryFormatter` is IMO universally a bad choice (with very few exceptions). I'm somewhat biased, but *one* example of a simple-to-use appendable serialization format is protocol-buffers, so I'll use that - note that this is a binary format, but simple to use. The first thing we need to do is add (probably via the nuget package manager in visual studio) [protobuf-net](http://nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net/). Then we need to tell it how to handle our types, which we do by annotation:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Person
{
    [ProtoMember(1)] public string Name { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)] public int ID { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(3)] public int Age { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(4)] public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Now we change our writing code to use the serializer (in an appendable way):

```
using (var file = File.Open("fileone.bin", FileMode.Append))
{
    Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(file, person,
        PrefixStyle.Base128, Serializer.ListItemTag);
}
```

and then to prove we can read them back at the end:

```
using (var file = File.OpenRead("fileone.bin"))
{
    foreach(var person in Serializer.DeserializeItems<Person>(
        file, PrefixStyle.Base128, Serializer.ListItemTag))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}",
            person.ID, person.Name, person.Age, person.Email);
    }
}
```